# Cut a string into two parts before any digit in js?

Tags: javascript

What I have:

```
add-category
add-exam
a-category1
a-category2
...
a-category[n]
```

What I need:
I need to cut string on two parts as 'a-category' and '1' or just 'add-exam' if no digit in row.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  have you tried looking it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let str = 'a-category2';
let splitStr = str.split(/(\d+)/);

console.log('string--->' + splitStr[0]);
console.log('digit---->' + splitStr[1]);
```